# Cannot execute testng test class with selenium - org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute test class with selenium using testng.

- org.seleniumhq.selenium - 3.0.1
- Java version - 1.8
- browser - Firefox 50.1.0

Initially I'm logging to the system and try access the button call 'Create Page'. The code as below,

```
private WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void testT() throws Exception {       
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   baseUrl = "http://test.test.com:8080/PageCreator";
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   driver.get(baseUrl);
   assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Log in to Creator Admin");
   driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
   driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
   driver.findElement(By.id("kc-login")).click();
   for (int second = 0;; second++) {
   if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
   try { if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("h1"))) break; } catch(Exception e) {}
   Thread.sleep(1000);

   driver.findElement(By.id("createPage")).click();
}
```

When execute this I'm getting an error as below.

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:
```

I tried below two solutions, but they also not worked.

First:

```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("createPage]")));
```

Second:

```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.id("createPage")));
```

Comment: What happened with your first and second solutions? Do you physically see this element on your screen or you need to scroll?

Comment: For the first solution also I got the same error. Yes element can physically see in my screen.

Comment: 2 things. First of all it will help if you can show us the html code of the element createPage that you are trying to locate, it could be under a hidden <li> so make sure to show code a bit before your actual element. Second thing is that your appraoch using a thread sleep is not a good practice,.You should used wait.until instead. If you post the html code I think I can help you locating the element via xPath (hit f12 in your browser and the right click the element you want to find and choose inspect)